# Making a GUI simulator in C

Tags: c, user-interface, graphics, simulator

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am writing a MicroMouse Simulator in C language. And I wanted something to visualize the way the maze is being solved like this -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9TkDgJNJso

I've been researching a way to accomplish this, but I haven't found anything with enough documentation to accomplish my goal.

I don't want to implement this using ASCII symbols, to me it doesn't look professional.

Is there any good GUI interfaces that I could use in C to help me accomplish this? And if so, how would I use it? I don't mind having to code in another language like Java or Python to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Can ncurses(http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) lib help you?

Comment: I looked at it, and I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I found something called graphics.h that I could possibly use, but I heard that it's very difficult to install on Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw the video that you want to make. After watching the video I feel you don't need a GUI library for this simulator program.

Here is a list of libraries that you can use.

1.[OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/info) This is a 3D graphics API which also can be used for 2D and can be used with both c/c++

2.[SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sdl/info) This library is easy to understand for a beginner. For your program this library is better and can be used with both c/c++.

3.[winBGIm](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) This is same as the graphics.h that you found and can be used both c/c++ but it is only for windows.

If you are looking for GUI library then here's a short list.

1.[GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gtk/info) This is written in c and is a popular GUI library for c. You can find a GUI editor for gtk forms called  [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) which enables quick & easy development of user interfaces.

2.[WxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wxwidgets/info) This is written in c++ so you have to use c++ rather than c.

3.[FLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fltk/info)

There are many more libraries besides these which you can find in google. You said

> I do not mind having to code in another language like Java or Python to accomplish my goal.

Then for java you can use [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) and If you are windows developer then use the windows form application in visual c++; then development of your program will be very easy.

Answer (score 4):

SDL is one of candidate for C in order to make GUI Simulation. [Lazyfoo](http://lazyfoo.net/) is one of the best site I found for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is strongly portable. It's written in C and there're a lot of documentation and [tutorials](http://www.sdltutorials.com/).